# iPhone: How to identify my app's version submitted on app store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

I have email funcitonality in my app and in email I want to send the version of my app submittd on app store

How can I do this?
provide me solution if you have

thans in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString* version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the version number as a string, just call:

```
NSString *version = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"];
```

If you want to put some text together:

```
NSString *version = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Version %@",  [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleVersion"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleShortVersionString"]
```